# Scanner object in while and do-while

Tags: java

I've got this code from github and  I decided to use in my code but with do-while syntax. The original code had no error or warning, but my code does.

original

```
public static char getChar(){
    char input = 0;
    Scanner keyIn;
    boolean notValid = true;
    while(notValid){
        keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);  //no warning
        try{
            input = keyIn.nextLine().charAt(0);
            notValid = false;
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.err.print("Input Error - Non-Character\n");
            System.err.print("Enter Again:\n");
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

in my code

```
public static char setOperend(){    
    char operand = 0;
    Scanner keyIn;
    boolean notValid = true;
    do{ 
        keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);     //warning:Resource leak: 'keyIn' is never closed
        try{
            operand= keyIn.nextLine().charAt(0);
            notValid = false;
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.err.print("애러 : 문자가 아닙니다.");
            System.err.print("다시 입력하세요.");
        }
    }while(notValid );
    return operand;
}
```

In terms of the fact that original code doesn't need `keyIn.close()`(which gets me confused as well), I guess it's because when do-while executes at first, compiler knows that it executes without any condition so thinks it has to be closed while original has the condition to check and maybe doesn't need to be closed (in case when condition never fulfilled). But both of them seem the same to me. Because original has this line`boolean notValid = true;`, it should execute at least once as well.

- Why `while` doesn't need `close()`, while `do-while` does.
- Is `close()` necessary?

Comment: Well, first things first: it makes no sense to write `new Scanner(System.in)` into a loop.

Comment: @cricket_007 There is no warning that can be mostly ignored. They can be explained or remedied, but not ignored.

Comment: So the ultimate solution is not to use `new Scanner(System.in)` in loop. Is that right? cause I don't want to see any warning. :( But still I want to know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the reason you're getting a warning in the second example is that the compiler can be certain that the loop will be executed at least once, thereby creating the Scanner. In the first version, the compiler just notices that the while loop *might* not happen if the variable is not true (although in this case it clearly is).

Others have (wrongly in my opinion) pointed out that you should *always* close the Scanner. That's most often not a good idea when your Scanner is wrapped around System.in, since that will close System.in:

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.
>    [Oracle Java Documentation - Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Since [System.in is an InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), which [implements the Closeable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), that means you will not be able to receive any more input from the user ever again - probably not what you want.

As for a solution, I'd do the following:

```
public static char setOperend(){    
    @SuppressWarnings("resource") // We don't want to close System.in
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean notValid = true;
    char operand = 0;

    do{             
        try{
            operand= keyIn.nextLine().charAt(0);
            notValid = false;
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.err.print("애러 : 문자가 아닙니다.");
            System.err.print("다시 입력하세요.");
        }
    }while(notValid );

    return operand;
}
```

This takes care of the warning without you having to call `close()` on System.in. It also solves the "problem" in your code where you create a new instance of `Scanner` for every iteration of the loop, which is unnecessary (and frankly quite ugly).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't get a warning with the original code, is that the compiler thinks the loop might not ever happen because it is dependent on a variable. However, with do-while loops, the code within the loop is always runs at least once, that is why it is happening. If you set it to `while(true)` you will get the same warning.

**original**
Both ways should call `close()` **Update** Should not call `close()` as explained by @BadCash

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought. Thank you for the answer though :)

Comment: Except calling `close()` on `System.in` is probably not something you'd want to do. And that's implicitly what you're doing when you're closing a Scanner on System.in. Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Yes, but that source is an input stream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in So why wouldn't you want to close it after using it?

Comment: Yes, and InputStream implements the Closeable interface, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html . So again - if you never want to get any input from the user again, it's fine. But that's probably not what most folks want.

Comment: @BadCash I just saw your explanation down below. Thanks for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 0):

If this scanner has not yet been closed then with `close()`, make you sure that scanner is closed, but if this scanner is already closed then setting this method, will have no effect.

And doesn't need to call `new Scanner(System.in)` into a loop, e.g: everytime that you do a nextLine(), it will do new Scanner!